# I need help with sprinkles

Tags: particles, workflow

Im brand new to Blender, so as many newbies do, I've been watching the Blender Guru Donut Beginner Guide. I've gone through all of level 1 without a problem, but the first part of level 2 (the sprinkles) is where I have been having a big problem.

When I attempted to put the sprinkles on my delectable donut for the first time, they spawned under the surface of the donut, I tried again and got the same result. I went away and when I came back to try again, the sprinkles wouldn't spawn at all.

I have looked at a lot of other questions on this site but haven't found any that help me much, I have looked for videos addressing the issues and still couldn't resolve the issue.

Comment: maybe you need to recalculate the normals of the donut, or make sure the origin of the sprinkle is at the center of its geometry?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you accidentally moved the cursor.

Select the donut press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and select the option *Cursor to Active*. Then try to add the sprinkles

Answer (score 0):

Press *Emissions*, its one of the drop down menus above the *Render* in the particle setting.

There you will find another dropdown box labeled *Source*, there you have to press *Use Modifier Stack*.